# Is there a list somewhere of common/useful R functions that are implemented in C

Tags: r, c, performance

In Advanced R by Hadley Wickham in [Chapter 24.5](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/perf-improve.html#vectorise)
He says:

> Instead, vectorisation means finding the existing R function that is implemented in C and most closely applies to your problem.

I was wondering if there is a list of such functions somewhere to refer to.
Thanks

Comment: I think this passage is misleading. You're not generally supposed to hunt for functions that are implemented in C. What Hadley almost certainly meant instead was that you should use *existing*, predefined functions in such cases, instead of implementing your own using `lapply`. Hadley, as an R expert, happens to know which of those functions are implemented in C but even he won’t care 99% of the time.

Comment: Ok, but do we not need these predefined functions to be implemented in C in order to be faster then just using your own function written in R. That is what would give improvements in performance, and that's why I was wondering whether there is a list or a way to determine whether a function has been implemented in   C.

Comment: It's not that simple. First off, the functions might not be implemented in C but instead in C++, Fortran or Rust. This doesn't matter, of course; all that matters is that they are compiled. Secondly, even if a function is implemented in R (i.e. not compiled), it might still internally call compiled functions, and thus be very efficient (both `mean` and `sd` are examples of that). Thirdly, R is extensible: it has packages. So there can't be an exhaustive list, and such a list would anyway be unpractically long. Don't worry about it too much.

Comment: Ok great, thank you for this. So the predefined functions are just more likely to be more efficient.

Comment: Actually I have another question. Lets say you have a for loop that in each iteration it calls a function that is implemented in C. Is the C code compiled at each iteration, or is it compiled on the first iteration then the next iterations just use the compiled code. Or if the function is from a package, will the C code be precompiled during the installation of the package.

Comment: @DylanDijk The C code is compiled when R or the containing package is compiled (either before or at installation time). Not when your code is executed.

Comment: Somewhat related, perhaps helpful: https://www.noamross.net/archives/2014-04-16-vectorization-in-r-why/